# how do i limit the searchbynamelike property in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

so here is my question what i want to do is that searchbynamelike property should give the exact result

as my string is "Hello"
so the findByNameLike("%Hello%")
it will all the result even if h is here or e or l and so on
but what i want is that if i have full hello then only it should give result
the reason being is i have hello in various places in a db table so when someone search for hello it should return all results where hello is found, but not when even if "h" is searched..
how can i achieve this in grails ...help..!!!

Comment: should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

In your case, don't use `%...%` sign in string. It'll give you all results matching anywhere `hello` is found in your string.
use: `findByNameIlike("Hello")`

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar search by using **[Criteria Query](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)** .

Just use nodes like **eq** or  **like** according to your need.